# Modal fecha mesmo clicando sobre ela

Tags: html, css, html5, modal, bootstrap-4

a modal abre normalmente, porém não posso usá-la. Qualquer lugar onde clico a modal fecha, a proposta inicial é que pudesse escrever e-mail e senha.

```css
.postagem {
  height: 100px;
}

#degrade {
  background: linear-gradient(80deg, #151515, #0404B4);
}

#transição {
  background: #0404B4;
}

#transição:hover {
  background: #013ADF;
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.entrar {
  color: #013ADF;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}

.menu2 {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--Barra de NAVEGAÇÂO-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-inverse">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- Inicio Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#botaotoggle">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <!--Fim Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="botaotoggle">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#janela">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entrar</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
<!--INICIO DA MODAL-->

<form class="modal fade" id="janela">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="data-content">

      <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title"> Fazer Login </h3>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
      </div>

      <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->

      <!--BODY DA MODAL-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Digite Seu e-mail" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Digite Sua senha" name="senha">
        </div>

      </div>



      <!--BODY DA MODAL-->

      <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->

      <div class="modal-footer">


        <!--botao cancelar-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Cancelar
            </button>

        <!--botao logar-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Logar
            </button>



      </div>



      <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->

    </div>

  </div>

</form>


<!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
<!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que vc monte sua estrutura o mais próximo possível do que diz a documentação. Então usar classes do `modal` no `form` não é legal. Tente colocar o `form` inteiro dentro da estrutura do `modal` que seria o mais indicado. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que eu fiz um CSS para deixar exatamente como no modelo que vc postou, então o modal fica sem fundo e sem borda, para mudar isso use a classe `.override` que fiz no CSS

Seque o código da imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .postagem {
  height: 100px;
}
#degrade {
  background: linear-gradient(80deg, #151515, #0404B4);
}
#transição {
  background: #0404B4;
}
#transição:hover {
  background: #013ADF;
}
.radius {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.entrar {
  color: #013ADF;
}
#menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}
.menu2 {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
}
.modal-content.override {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Barra de NAVEGAÇÂO-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- Inicio Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#botaotoggle">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <!--Fim Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="botaotoggle">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#janela">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entrar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--INICIO DA MODAL-->


<div class="modal fade" id="janela" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content override">
      <div class="data-content">

        <form>
          <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title"> Fazer Login </h3>
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->
          <!--BODY DA MODAL-->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Digite Seu e-mail" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Digite Sua senha" name="senha">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--BODY DA MODAL-->
          <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--botao cancelar-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Cancelar
            </button>
            <!--botao logar-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Logar
            </button>
          </div>
          <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando a classe errada na div dentro da modal: em vez de `class="data-content"`, o correto é `class="modal-content"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Note que seu modal nem está sendo renderizado corretamente: está sem a
>   caixa branca padrão.

**Veja abaixo como fica com a devida correção:**

```css
.postagem {
  height: 100px;
}

#degrade {
  background: linear-gradient(80deg, #151515, #0404B4);
}

#transição {
  background: #0404B4;
}

#transição:hover {
  background: #013ADF;
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.entrar {
  color: #013ADF;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}

.menu2 {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  right: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--Barra de NAVEGAÇÂO-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-inverse">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- Inicio Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#botaotoggle">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <!--Fim Botao toggler(so aparece tela pequena) -->
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="botaotoggle">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#janela">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entrar</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
<!--INICIO DA MODAL-->

<form class="modal fade" id="janela">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title"> Fazer Login </h3>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
      </div>

      <!--HEAD DA MODAL-->

      <!--BODY DA MODAL-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Digite Seu e-mail" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Digite Sua senha" name="senha">
        </div>

      </div>



      <!--BODY DA MODAL-->

      <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->

      <div class="modal-footer">


        <!--botao cancelar-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Cancelar
            </button>

        <!--botao logar-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Logar
            </button>



      </div>



      <!--FOOTER DA MODAL-->

    </div>

  </div>

</form>


<!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
<!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```